# Magento 2 Development in Team

Tags: php, mysql, magento

we are currently changing from Magento 1.9 to 2.3 and want to develop in a team. With Magento 1.9 we could relatively simply rewrite the config so that we could use the same database, version the project with SVN and each developer could work on his domain. As an example:

- magento.tk (developer 1)
- magento.sg (developer 2)
- etc.

Now we have adjusted the problem with the Base URL in the app/etc/env.php:

```
    'system' => [
    'default' => [
        'system' => [
            'smtp' => [
                'host' => 'localhost',
                'port' => '25'
            ]
        ],
        'web' => [
            'unsecure' => [
                'base_url' => 'http://magento.tk/',
                'base_link_url' => '{{unsecure_base_url}}'
            ],
            'secure' => [
                'base_url' => 'https://magento.tk/',
                'base_link_url' => '{{secure_base_url}}'
            ],
            'default' => [
                'front' => 'cms'
            ],
            'cookie' => [
                'cookie_domain' => 'test'
            ]
        ],
    ],
```

That works so far also, but always only on one domain. After changing the env.php, we run setup:upgrade, which makes the shop work locally, but since we probably use the same database, we can't develop with more than one person, otherwise we get the following error:

```
1 exception(s): Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): The configuration file has changed. Run the "app:config:import" or the "setup:upgrade" command to synchronize the configuration.
```

When the other developer does that, everyone else gets it. Is there a way to get it to run locally?

**local performance:**

The other problem is performance. If we call the project locally or online in dev mode (caching is off because of development), then the frontend and backend loads very long and is sluggish. The installed Magento version 2.3 is installed without big plugins and has only one theme installed, but the loading times are catastrophic - both backend and frontend load very long and delay the development. Are there any tips here to make the system work reasonably well?

I would be very grateful for any help and tips you might need :-)

Answer (score 0):

**1/ Methodology**

You should review your work methodology a bit because of Magento 2. With changing Magento version, you can change tools to newers too.

**Docker** is a great tool to replicate development environment.

An other **versionning methodology** can be use. I don't know SVN (I'm using Git). But in that case :

- we have a development branch, eveyone i working on is own environment and his own branch.
- when any task is finished, developer merge dev branch in his own branch to fix conflicts
- then, the developer merge his own branch in dev branch

**2/ Local perforances**

I am used to use cache even for dev... Else, performances can be soo awful !

- [Install & configure Redis](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/redis/config-redis.html)
- Enable all cache except `Blocks HTML output` and `Page Cache`

Sure, you'll have to clear cache when changing config, products and categories... But as developper, it's not our job (and why not use the `php bin/magento c:c;php bin/magento c:f;` CLI command).

With that simple tricks, **you will earn hours every weeks**

Comment: Okay, thank you for your answer. But I´ve currently following question about our config (env.php) and the base_url. Do you have your own repository local with one domain? For example magento.local for every developer and do you have only a host entry for that?

Comment: Docker allow all dev to have the same local environnement, the same database but a different env.php file. Our dev server (that share database with dev environement) is on developement branch, where the developer work is merged.